# linux c detect attached device, load and link drivers, return the device file system entry

Tags: c, linux, file, mount

I have an api function whose description is as follows

> attach()
>
> Causes a new device to become known to the system or verifies that the device is already attached.
>
> If the device descriptor is found and the device is not already attached, attach() links to its file manager and device driver, and places their addresses in a new device table
>   entry. If the attach fails, -1 is returned and the appropriate error code is placed in the global variable errno .
>
> name is a pointer to the name of the device descriptor. 
>   mode is the access mode.

I have implemented it with `mount` system call. Do not know if it is correct way of doing.
my code is:

```
#define MOUNT_DIR               "/mnt/iso" 
#define FILE_SYSTEM             "ext2"
typedef struct devtab {
/* TODO this structure taken from mwosppc/SRC/DPIO/DEFS/io.h
    need to check which all fields required currently used only 
    dummy attribute here for compilation */
    u_int32
        v_fm_globs,             /* file manager total static globals pointer*/
        v_dr_globs,             /* driver globals pointer */
        v_rsrv[2];              /* reserved space */
} dev_list, *Dev_list;



dev_list *attach(const char *name,
                 int mode)
{
    dev_list * deviceList;
    FILE* ExecutionResult;
    int deviceCount;
    int deviceIndex[50];
    char cmdExecute[50], finalOutputCmd[50000], outputCmd[100];
    int i;
    int bytes = 0;
    char* temp = 0;
    switch(mode)
    {
        //case FAM_READ:
        case S_IREAD:
            mount(name, MOUNT_DIR, FILE_SYSTEM, MS_MGC_VAL | MS_RDONLY, "");
            break;
        case S_IWRITE:
        //case FAM_WRITE:
            mount(name, MOUNT_DIR, FILE_SYSTEM, MS_MGC_VAL, "");
            break;
        default:
            mount(name, MOUNT_DIR, FILE_SYSTEM, MS_MGC_VAL, "");
            break;
    }
    strcpy(cmdExecute, "lshw -short");
    ...parse output in deviceList....

    return  deviceList;
}
```

My doubts are:

- I think I should return the dev node created for the new device, so that another function can open the device and do read write operation on it?
- But then how do I get dev node of the mounted device?
- Then how to link to the file manager and device driver? Is it needed to link to driver or does linux automatically do that?
- Will mount be useful for all types of devices, block, serial, network etc?
- What does mount system call do?

Comment: please have a look at [How do i ask a good question on stackoverflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)